# Tensorflow slow for dot product and matrix multiplication

Tags: python, performance, numpy, tensorflow

I am currently trying to write some linear algebra code in Tensorflow and compare the performance to a numpy implementation. I struggle the problem that for repetitive matrix vector multiplications or repetitive matrix-matrix multiplications the Tensorflow code is by orders of magnitudes slower. I am currently testing Tensorflow without a GPU just using the CPU. My intention is to implement my project in Tensorflow such that it runs fast on both, CPU and GPU depending what the user has available. The matrix sizes can vary between roughly 10x10 to very large matrices. I am willing to accept a little perfomance loss for small matrices when using tensorflow for having one common codebase as long it is not that drastic as below.

Here are two examples with timings from IPython:

```python
%%timeit
dim = 10000
m1 = np.random.uniform(dim)
m2 = np.random.uniform(dim,dim)
tmp = np.dot(m2,m1)
for i in range(200):
    tmp = np.dot(m2,tmp)
```

This takes 151 µs ± 6.56 µs.

Now with Tensorflow:

```python
%%timeit
a1 = tf.random.uniform([dim,dim])
a2 = tf.random.uniform([dim])
tmp = tf.tensordot(a1,a2,1)
for i in range(200):
    tmp = tf.tensordot(a1,tmp,1)
```

Only that takes 1.07 s ± 128 ms. The evaluation then takes again 7.5s.

```python
sess = tf.Session()
with sess.as_default():
    out = tmp.eval()
```

I observed the same tendency when using matmul.

Thank you very much for any hints!

Peter

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems in your code.

1. `np.random.uniform(dim)` and `np.random.uniform(dim,dim)` are returning two float numbers instead of two matrices. You probably want to use `np.random.rand(dim)` and `np.random.rand(dim,dim)`
2. You *timeit* the creation of graph, as well as the generation of random matrix. I would suggest only timeit `np.dot` and `sess.run()`.

Following is a benchmark code for `tf.matmul` and `np.dot`, which is adapted from [here](https://github.com/yaroslavvb/stuff/blob/master/matmul_benchmark.py)

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import os
import time


n = 10000
dtype = tf.float32
with tf.device("/cpu:0"):
    matrix1 = tf.Variable(tf.ones((n, n), dtype=dtype))
    matrix2 = tf.Variable(tf.ones((n, n), dtype=dtype))
    product = tf.matmul(matrix1, matrix2)

# avoid optimizing away redundant nodes
config = tf.ConfigProto(graph_options=tf.GraphOptions(optimizer_options=tf.OptimizerOptions(opt_level=tf.OptimizerOptions.L0)))
sess = tf.Session(config=config)

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
iters = 10

# pre-warming
sess.run(product.op)

start = time.time()
for i in range(iters):
    sess.run(product.op)
end = time.time()
elapsed = (end - start)
print('tensorflow cpu: %d x %d matmul took: %.2f sec' % (n, n, elapsed/iters))

########### numpy test ###########
np_m1 = np.ones((n,n),dtype=np.float32)
np_m2 = np.ones((n,n),dtype=np.float32)
start = time.time()
for i in range(iters):
    np.dot(np_m1,np_m2)
end = time.time()
elapsed = (end - start)
print('numpy: %d x %d matmul took: %.2f sec' % (n, n, elapsed/iters))
```

In my machine, the output is

```py
# tensorflow cpu: 10000 x 10000 matmul took: 2.79 sec
# numpy: 10000 x 10000 matmul took: 4.36 sec
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I can definitely see the flaws in my implementation. However, I don't consider your comparison as a fair comparison since all the graph definition stuff and initialization is not part of the benchmark. If I include them into the benchmark, then numpy is by a lot smaller. This holds also for increasing the matrix dimension. Especially here, the session init can take easily 10x the acutual calculation time (not fixed for increasing matrix dimension). Also, when including the for repetitive matrix mult. definition as above, the graph building is much slower...

Comment: @P.Egli Actually, the time of creating graph could be ignored compared with training time in practice when you  training a neural network. Also, since you’re comparing the matrix multiplication, graph building is not considered as a part of matrix computation.

Comment: Thank you for that clarification. Yeah, maybe I should have stated that I try to speed up some linear algebra calculations which will only run once. This is completely different than for training a neuronal network. My intention was to speed up a large number of matrix multiplications for some system that I model. Therefore, I am kind of interested in a "one-time shot". I would be very happy, if you have any ideas how to speed them up...

Comment: @P.Egli Maybe you can check blas libraries that includes GEMM functions. They optimize matrix multiplication somehow. Hopefully you can get some insights. :)